# How to pass parameters in batch file and zip the file using 7z.exe?

Tags: batch, batch-file, zip, 7-zip, pkzip

I need to create a batch file as per below requirements

1) pass **path1** & **path2** while running the batch file

exl: **testrun.bat E:\ERP\test1.txt E:\ERP\header.txt**

2) Need to store these command line paths values in batch file

exl: **var1=E:\ERP\test1.txt var2=E:\ERP\header.txt**

3) zip the **path1** using PKZIPW.exe or 7z.exe and create new o/p zip file

exl: **7z.exe u -tzip E:\Erp\Test1.zip var1**

4) copy **path2** in newly created o/p file

**exl: copy /b var2+test1.zip E:\Erp\Final_output.zip**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET var1=%1
SET var2=%2

E:\Erp\7z.exe u -tzip E:\Erp\Test1.zip %var1%
copy /b %var2%\test1.zip E:\Erp\Final_output.zip
```

Comment: Its giving below mentioned error "**7z.exe is not recognized as internal or external command,operable program or batch file**"

Comment: 7z.exe would be under program-files (perhaps x86). The script should use `setlocal` and temporarily extend `PATH` to address this problem.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey : got it... as i was running the batch from desired folder locn so I skipped full path for exe.. but now as i'm passing full path and its working..